# Test host not found Xcode 13.3.1 BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR variable changed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testing

**TL;DR**

$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR):

- Was `.../Products/Debug-iphoneos/...` and `.../Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/...` in Xcode 13.3.0
- Now it's `.../Products/Debug/...` in Xcode 13.3.1

**Questions:**

- How to get the path right in Xcode 13.3.1?
- Or is this (another) Xcode bug?

**More info:**

I've just updated my Xcode from 13.3.0 to 13.3.1 and I've noticed several changes that are not even mentioned in the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13_3_1-release-notes)

First, to target the iPhone family: `TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1`
It has become: `SDKROOT = iphoneos`

My problem is that my test target, which relies on the app target, is not being found anymore.

My research so far:

- `Test Target > General > Host Application` This is set to the App target, all good.
- `Test Target > Build Settings > TEST_HOST` is `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/MyApp.app/MyApp`
- My surprise when I run the test suite is that I get the following message:

```
Could not find test host for MyAppTests: TEST_HOST evaluates to ".../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp/Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app/MyApp"
```

And that does not exist!

So I go to my Finder and this should be the correct path:

```
.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp
```

or

```
.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/MyApp
```

Thank you!

Comment: Any updates? Same error